# generating a makefile for the dumb

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I got 10 C files.
10 h files all in one folder.
I need those files to create 1 executable in the same folder using unix makefile.

EDIT :
the soultion

create a file named "makefile"
write the following make sure you have a single TAB before the word "gcc" this will create a.out executable

```
all:
    gcc *.c
```

if you need flags just add them for example to make the filename BOB:

```
all:
    gcc *.c -o BOB
```

Comment: Why can't you create the makefile yourself?

Comment: What have you tried? There are some good tutorials on makefiles on the web. Google it!

Comment: search for a sample makefile, tailor it for your needs.

Comment: You haven't shown any effort at all on something that is really simple. So I am voting to close, I will remove my vote if you post something you've tried.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I failed to find any simple example.

Comment: I don't know that it's an exact duplicate, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576292/create-linux-make-build-file/3576355

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I fail to find any of those examples simple.

Comment: You need *a simple tool that will create a makefile?* Or you need a simple makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want what you say you want, but how about:

```
all:
    gcc *.c
```

Comment: will this include my H files? and create a simple executable?

Comment: .h files should get included in your .c files with `#include` directives, not on the command line. Yes, this will compile all the .c files in that folder. Stick it in a file called `Makefile`, and run `make`. Your executable will be called `a.out`. You can get a different name by adding `-o filename` to the `gcc` command.

Comment: after switching the spaces to tabs it complies, but ruiing the program causes segmentation fault :(

Comment: @NahumLitvin: then your code is buggy. Tackle one problem at a time.

Comment: That's an issue with the program, not a Makefile issue.

Comment: this is a perfect solution for my case. I have no idea why I got so much scorn trying to find it.

Comment: @NahumLitvin, I'm glad I could help and I'm sorry we snarled at you, but you've been here for months; you should understand better how to ask a question. GOOD: *"I don't know UNIX, so even the simple Make tutorials are opaque to me."* BAD: "*I am not a UNIXer. not interested in learning. don't waste my time. gimme simple answer"* If you indicate an unwillingness to put in effort (even at grammar, punctuation and spelling) then people will resent your requests for help.

Comment: @Beta why is it bad? I know that Linux have its advantages. 
the fact is I don't have the time nor the will to learn it as I choose to follow other paths of knowledge. I made a reasonable effort to find the solution you presented over the internet without success. I believe that I clearly stated my situation. And you guys are just bullies. harassing those weaker then you.

Comment: @NahumLitvin: These guys have spent time trying to help you. Please consider treating them civilly, instead of terming them "bullies". Plonk from me.

Answer (score 1):

"missing separator" is commonly caused by a missing tab in front of a command line. The lines with `$(CXX)` need to be indented by a tab - not 8 spaces, not any number of spaces, but a tab.

Additionally, I don't think that empty lines between rule and commands are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from obviously writing the Makefile yourself, you can also use CMake which is a convenient build system generator.

A simple example of a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(yourproject C)
add_executable(yourexecutable file1.c file1.h file2.c file2.h ...)
```

You can then do in a terminal:

```
$ cmake .
$ make
```

and your executable will be built.

Be careful however that the generated makefile uses cmake and is therefore not distributable per se.

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt file is redistributable, though, and your project can be built by anyone who has CMake installed on their system ;)