# Makefile for Linux from Xcode-written C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I've written a simple c++ program on Xcode, all contained within ONE FILE called huffmanGenerator.cpp. The program reads input from a file on the user's computer, and writes output to a file saved to their computer.

The instructor has asked us to create a makefile so that our programs compile and run with g++ OR gcc in Linux; however she never showed us how to do so, and when the class asked for help, her answer was we could figure it out.

I found many links online, but they're all very confusing as this is all new to me, and most of them fail to answer even the most basic questions like what kind of file should the makefile be? Is it a .txt? Should I just save one in word?

Please help do what the instructor won't, enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: The file should generally be called 'makefile' or 'Makefile'. It has no extension (these don't matter in Linux). You should most definitely not make it in Word, as whitespace is meaningful in a makefile. You should use an editor like nano/vi/emacs/etc.

Comment: Here's a [quick tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) which can help you get started. I you want a more in depth understanding of `make`, check out the [GNU `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create linux make/build file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576292/create-linux-make-build-file)

Comment: That other post is far more involved, and going from windows to Linux.. I'm going from Mac to linux, and my program only includes headers from the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what kind of file should the makefile be?

It should be a plaintext file called `Makefile` or `makefile`. The reason the name matters is because when you run the `make` command, it looks for a file with this name by default for directions on how to compile your code. You can also name it whatever you want as long as you specify the name when you run it (make **-f** *filename*).

> Is it a .txt?

No, it has no extension. Extensions don't mean that much in *nix.

> Should I just save one in word? (Assume you mean Microsoft Word.)

No, definitely not. Whitespace (tabs/spaces/new lines) have meaning in these files, so you should use an editor that won't add formatting to the file. Something like pico/vi/etc.

Here is an example of a makefile, that I think does what you are asking.

```
# You can change your compiler to gcc / g++ here.
CC=g++
# Add whatever flags you want to use here.
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) huffmanGenerator.cpp -o huffmanGenerator
#Use something like this to run `make clean` which deletes your object files, so you can do a fresh compile.    
#clean:
#   rm -rf *o huffmanGenerator
```

As a side note, you would be served well not to blame your professor for not spelling out everything for you. When you graduate, you will often be given tasks that have no other directions than a set of requirements and a deadline. You will need to figure it out. You could have easily made this make file by visiting http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/ (search google for 'makefile tutorial').

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help and response. I don't blame the professor, I'm simply stating that some clearer help would be great. This is the first time I ever come across any of this, I'm still in the very beginning stages of my education and I'm probably as lost as can be. All the tutorials online only create more questions in my head and the whole thing gets progressively worst, so it's highly frustrating that when i go to my instructor for help i get nothing. I don't want to be evaluated on my ability to teach myself things, or google things. Anyways, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem - I wasn't trying to lecture you, I only said that cause I was in the same spot as you a few years ago. It is easy to blame professors for stuff (and sometimes, they really are no help), but the best thing to do is become really good at figuring stuff out for yourself, and that can only come from practice. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile should be called Makefile.  It is just a text file.

You need a text editor.  There are many to choose from, vim, emacs, nano, pico, ..., etc.

Open a command line and run, say

```
$ pico Makefile
```

Then you would enter the contents of the Makefile

```
all:
    g++ -o huffmanGenerator huffmanGenerator.cpp
```

Save and exit and run make

```
$ make
```